# Why is the catch statement being ignored here?

Tags: java, try-catch, stack-trace

This is practice code from a book and i'm learning about try/catch statements.

The first method shown calls for the load method an retrieves two images. The error in this code is that the name of the first img in the resources file is called "welcome.png" but as you can see, it says "welcomee.png"(extra e at the end of welcome). When I run the code, it doesn't print out the code in the catch statement. It does show the stacktrace(because it does that regardless), but it doesn't print out " Error while reading: filename". Why is this?

```
   public class Resources {

    public static BufferedImage welcome, iconimage;

    public static void load() {
        welcome = loadImage("welcomee.png");
        iconimage = loadImage("iconimage.png");
    }

    private static AudioClip loadSound(String filename) {
        URL fileURL = Resources.class.getResource("/resources/" + filename);
        return Applet.newAudioClip(fileURL);
    }

    private static BufferedImage loadImage(String filename) {
        BufferedImage img = null;
        try {
            img = ImageIO.read(Resources.class.getResourceAsStream("/resources/" + filename));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("Error while reading: " + filename);
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return img;
    }
}
```

Comment: Show the full exception message and stack trace.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're catching an `IOException`, but [`Class.getResourceAsStream`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getResourceAsStream-java.lang.String-) doesn't throw an `IOException` if the resource is not found; it just returns null. And [`ImageIO.read`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/imageio/ImageIO.html#read-java.io.InputStream-) doesn't throw an `IOException` if the argument is null; it throws an `IllegalArgumentException`.

I suggest you refactor the code this way:

```
private static BufferedImage loadImage(String filename) {
    try (InputStream in = Resources.class.getResourceAsStream("/resources/" + filename)) {
        if (in == null) throw new IOException("Resource not found");
        return ImageIO.read(in);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println("Error while reading: " + filename);
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }
}
```

This will ensure you handle the error, and the use of the [try-with-resources](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html) statement makes sure the stream is always closed after use (which `ImageIO.read` does not do). The direct `return` statement is perhaps a bit cleaner as it obviates the need for the `img` variable.

You should also consider, rather than returning null on error, to throw (or rethrow) some exception to the caller, such as an [`UncheckedIOException`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/UncheckedIOException.html), since a null return value will only cause errors elsewhere once you try to make use of it, and an exception thrown directly from the point of the problem will be more meaningful than some `NullPointerException` thrown later.

Comment: ... and that information would have been in the stack trace that was not supplied in the question.

Answer (score 1):

You can only catch `IOException`. If you want to catch all type of exception, use `catch(Exception e)`.

Comment: I'll just have to do more studying to understand what this fully means.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `catch(Exception e){...}` instead. It is a way to check if it is just another exception or if it is not an exception, but a run-time error.

You can specify certain catch statements with certain exceptions later in the development process, if needed.